# Subsetting based on dates pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, date, subset

I have a date column which after converting to datetime it looks like this:

```
 data['date']=pd.to_datetime(data[date])
 2018-07-20 00:00:00
```

When I am trying to subset using this:

```
 beg = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-07-20', '%Y-%m-%d')
 end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-07-25', '%Y-%m-%d')
 data = data.loc[(data['date']>=beg) & (data['date']<=end)]
```

I get this error:

ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you print `df.columns` to the question

Comment: It is a very large dataset so df.columns will print out a lot of variable names.'date' is in there though for what it is worth

Comment: Any my guess is that more than one of them is `date`, which is why you should look at it.

Comment: ah I see. I will check

Comment: just 1 'date' column

Comment: Wait a minute, I just tried to sort by 'date' and got this error: 
ValueError: Cannot sort by duplicate column ['efctv_date']

Comment: So, there is a duplicate column. But when I print df.column I only see it once

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use [partial string indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) by moving that date into the dataframe index.

MCVE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100),index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01',periods=100, freq='45D'))
df.loc['2010-05-10':'2013-12-04']
```

Output:

```
             0
2010-05-16   3
2010-06-30   4
2010-08-14   5
2010-09-28   6
2010-11-12   7
2010-12-27   8
2011-02-10   9
2011-03-27  10
2011-05-11  11
2011-06-25  12
2011-08-09  13
2011-09-23  14
2011-11-07  15
2011-12-22  16
2012-02-05  17
2012-03-21  18
2012-05-05  19
2012-06-19  20
2012-08-03  21
2012-09-17  22
2012-11-01  23
2012-12-16  24
2013-01-30  25
2013-03-16  26
2013-04-30  27
2013-06-14  28
2013-07-29  29
2013-09-12  30
2013-10-27  31
```

Comment: Ah, interesting solution. I kinda need my index however for other purposes (I guess I could just turn the current index into a variable).